# Set var="NEW.this_word_column" in a trigger function if "word" is present in a column name

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql, pattern-matching

## Context

I'm using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) 10.12.

I want to be able to fire a trigger function on some specific tables with geographic data.

This trigger function is designed to create a [PotGIS](https://postgis.net/) point into a column `geom` from `lat` and `lon` values.
I want to apply this same trigger function over several tables each time a new row is inserted.
The naming of columns holding latitude and longitude values is not consistent across tables but it follows a pattern...

What I am 100% sure is that:
 1. there are always two columns containing latitude and longitude values,
 2. the name of theses columns are *not always* the same in the
    different tables (otherwise it would have been too simple), but the word 'latitude' and the word 'longitude'
    *always* appear in their name and never appear in other column names.

E.g. in table A:

> `_loc_longitude_` and `_loc_latitude_`

and in table B:

> `_building_longitude_center` and `_building_latitude_center`

for example (+ many others).

The trigger function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_point_with_latlon()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  DECLARE
      varlon := NULL;
      varlat := NULL;
  BEGIN
      IF to_jsonb(NEW) SIMILAR TO '.*longitude.*' THEN
          varlon := NEW.the_column_whith_longitude_in_its_name;
      END IF;
      IF to_jsonb(NEW) SIMILAR TO '.*latitude.*' THEN
          varlat := NEW.the_column_whith_latitude_in_its_name;
      END IF;
      NEW.geom = ST_MakePoint(varlon, varlat);
  END
  $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

With the following triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER make_point_with_latlon_but
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON schema.table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.make_point_with_latlon();

CREATE TRIGGER make_point_with_latlon_but
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON schema.table2
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.make_point_with_latlon();

CREATE TRIGGER make_point_with_latlon_but
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON schema.table3
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.make_point_with_latlon();

-- (...and many more other tables that need the same trigger).
```

I don't know how to search for the pattern `.*latitude.*` in the columns names passed to the function, and how to get their **value** into two variables that I can use to build the point with.
And my googling skills for searching these kind of stuff are far from perfect, hence returning noisy results.

## Question

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same function as a trigger for all these tables?

Comment: Yes, for basically always a same simple pre-processing task each time a new row is inserted from any API, isn't this a good idea?

Comment: I don't know if it is a good idea because you have not pointed out the purpose of this scenario. You only indicated a specific problem with your trigger. Perhaps adding why could help to get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and special variables: [TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Quoted from docs:

> When a PL/pgSQL function is called as a trigger, several special
>   variables are created automatically in the top-level block. They are:
>
> TG_TABLE_NAME: Data type name; the name of the table that caused the
>   trigger invocation.
>
> TG_TABLE_SCHEMA: Data type name; the name of the schema of the table
>   that caused the trigger invocation.

Given next example:

```
create table a (id int primary key, latitude int, longitude int);
create table b (id int primary key, _loc_latitude int, _loc_longitude int);
create table c (result text);
```

```
create function trg_tables()
returns trigger as
$$
declare
  varlat text;
  varlng text;
  cmd text;
  vallat int;
  vallng int;
begin  
  varlat := (select column_name
            from   information_schema.columns
            where  table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
                   and table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME
                   and column_name like '%latitude%');

  varlng := (select column_name
            from   information_schema.columns
            where  table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
                   and table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME
                   and column_name like '%longitude%');

  execute 'select $1.' || varlat
  using NEW
  into vallat;

  execute 'select $1.' || varlng
  using NEW
  into vallng;

  execute format('insert into c values (''lat: '' || ''%s'' || ''  lng '' || ''%s'' )',
                 vallat::text, vallng::text);

  return NEW;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

```
create trigger trg after insert on a
  for each row execute procedure trg_tables();
create trigger trg after insert on b
  for each row execute procedure trg_tables();
```

```
insert into a values (1,11,1);
insert into b values (1,20,2);
select * from c;

| result         |
| :------------- |
| lat: 11  lng 1 |
| lat: 20  lng 2 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7aee33dbe95a3b387bc732261d74cee)*

It's just an example on how to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA and special variables inside a trigger, but maybe a Postgres pro-user can give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. A lot. Does `varlat` and `varlng` hold the names of the columns or the values of the row being inserted for these columns? I'm guessing it's the name (I actually do need the 2 values corresponding to the 2 columns found on the table the trigger is fired) because when I try your nice solution, I'm facing an `invalid input syntax for type double precision: buildings_latitude_center`

Comment: Ok, but then how could I use the names found to actually access the values in the row being inserted, namely NEW."varlat" and NEW."varlng" which are float values?

Comment: Yes, great! The thing is that I get the error hereafter while trying to grab the lat, lon values into variables 'lat' 'lon' prior to using them for computations that will get exported as into `NEW.new_field` : `EXECUTE format(NEW.'%I', latcol) INTO lat;` is raising: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'%I'".` It sounds I cannot access `NEW.building_latitude_center` with this EXECUTE statement.